# How to animate Cards in android

Tags: java, android

How to animate Cards in android Card Game [Like](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.aifactory.spadesfree&hl=en) "Spades Free". My game is quite the same as crazy 8.i used android game development for dummies as a reference.but, i want to animate cards how can i do that.

public class GameView extends View {

```
private int screenW;
private int screenH;
private Context myContext;
private List<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
private int scaledCardW;
private int scaledCardH;
private Paint whitePaint;
private List<Card> myHand = new ArrayList<Card>();
private List<Card> oppHand = new ArrayList<Card>();
private int myScore = 0;
private int oppScore = 0;
private float scale;
private Bitmap cardBack;
private List<Card> discardPile = new ArrayList<Card>();
private boolean myTurn;
private ComputerPlayer computerPlayer = new ComputerPlayer();
private int movingCardIdx = -1;
private int movingX;
private int movingY;
private int validRank = 8;
private int validSuit = 0;
private Bitmap nextCardButton;
private int scoreThisHand = 0;

public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    myContext = context;
    scale = myContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;  
    whitePaint = new Paint();
    whitePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    whitePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    whitePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    whitePaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    whitePaint.setTextSize(scale*15);
}   

@Override
public void onSizeChanged (int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh){
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    screenW = w;
    screenH = h;
    Bitmap tempBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(myContext.getResources(), R.drawable.card_back);
    scaledCardW = (int) (screenW/8);
    scaledCardH = (int) (scaledCardW*1.28);
    cardBack = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tempBitmap, scaledCardW, scaledCardH, false); 
    nextCardButton = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.arrow_next); 
    initCards();
    dealCards();
    drawCard(discardPile);
    validSuit = discardPile.get(0).getSuit();
    validRank = discardPile.get(0).getRank();
    myTurn = new Random().nextBoolean();
    if (!myTurn) {
        makeComputerPlay();         
    }
}   

@Override 
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawText("Computer Score: " + Integer.toString(oppScore), 10, whitePaint.getTextSize()+10, whitePaint);
    canvas.drawText("My Score: " + Integer.toString(myScore), 10, screenH-whitePaint.getTextSize()-10, whitePaint);
    for (int i = 0; i < oppHand.size(); i++) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(cardBack, 
                i*(scale*5), 
                whitePaint.getTextSize()+(50*scale), 
                null);
    }   

    canvas.drawBitmap(cardBack, (screenW/2)-cardBack.getWidth()-10, (screenH/2)-(cardBack.getHeight()/2), null);
    if (!discardPile.isEmpty()) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(discardPile.get(0).getBitmap(), 
                          (screenW/2)+10, 
                          (screenH/2)-(cardBack.getHeight()/2), 
                          null);            
    }   

    if (myHand.size() > 7) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(nextCardButton, 
                screenW-nextCardButton.getWidth()-(30*scale), 
                screenH-nextCardButton.getHeight()-scaledCardH-(90*scale), 
                null);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < myHand.size(); i++) {
        if (i == movingCardIdx) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(myHand.get(i).getBitmap(), 
                    movingX, 
                    movingY, 
                    null);                      
        } else {
            if (i < 7) {
                canvas.drawBitmap(myHand.get(i).getBitmap(), 
                        i*(scaledCardW+5), 
                        screenH-scaledCardH-whitePaint.getTextSize()-(50*scale), 
                        null);                          
            }
        }   
    }
    invalidate();
}   

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int eventaction = event.getAction();   
        int X = (int)event.getX();
        int Y = (int)event.getY();

        switch (eventaction ) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if (myTurn) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                    if (X > i*(scaledCardW+5) && X < i*(scaledCardW+5) + scaledCardW && 
                        Y > screenH-scaledCardH-whitePaint.getTextSize()-(50*scale)) {
                        movingCardIdx = i;
                        movingX = X-(int)(30*scale);
                        movingY = Y-(int)(70*scale);
                    }
                }                   
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: 
            movingX = X-(int)(30*scale);
            movingY = Y-(int)(70*scale);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (movingCardIdx > -1 && 
                X > (screenW/2)-(100*scale) &&
                X < (screenW/2)+(100*scale) &&
                Y > (screenH/2)-(100*scale) &&
                Y < (screenH/2)+(100*scale) &&
                (myHand.get(movingCardIdx).getRank() == 8 ||
                 myHand.get(movingCardIdx).getRank() == validRank ||
                 myHand.get(movingCardIdx).getSuit() == validSuit)) {
                    validRank = myHand.get(movingCardIdx).getRank();
                    validSuit = myHand.get(movingCardIdx).getSuit();
                    discardPile.add(0, myHand.get(movingCardIdx));
                    myHand.remove(movingCardIdx);
                    if (myHand.isEmpty()) {
                        endHand();
                    } else {
                        if (validRank == 8) {
                            showChooseSuitDialog();                         
                        } else {
                            myTurn = false;
                            makeComputerPlay();                         
                        }                           
                    }
            }
            if (movingCardIdx == -1 && myTurn && 
                    X > (screenW/2)-(100*scale) &&
                    X < (screenW/2)+(100*scale) &&
                    Y > (screenH/2)-(100*scale) &&
                    Y < (screenH/2)+(100*scale)) {
                if (checkForValidDraw()) {
                    drawCard(myHand);                       
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(myContext, "You have a valid play.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            if (myHand.size() > 7 &&
                X > screenW-nextCardButton.getWidth()-(30*scale) &&
                Y > screenH-nextCardButton.getHeight()-scaledCardH-(90*scale) &&
                Y < screenH-nextCardButton.getHeight()-scaledCardH-(60*scale)) {
                    Collections.rotate(myHand, 1);
            }
            movingCardIdx = -1;
            break;
        } 
        invalidate();
        return true;      
}   

private void showChooseSuitDialog() {
    final Dialog chooseSuitDialog = new Dialog(myContext);
    chooseSuitDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    chooseSuitDialog.setContentView(R.layout.choose_suit_dialog);
    final Spinner suitSpinner = (Spinner) chooseSuitDialog.findViewById(R.id.suitSpinner);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            myContext, R.array.suits, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    suitSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    Button okButton = (Button) chooseSuitDialog.findViewById(R.id.okButton);
    okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            validSuit = (suitSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()+1)*100;
            String suitText = "";
            if (validSuit == 100) {
                suitText = "Diamonds";
            } else if (validSuit == 200) {
                suitText = "Clubs";
            } else if (validSuit == 300) {
                suitText = "Hearts";
            } else if (validSuit == 400) {
                suitText = "Spades";
            }
            chooseSuitDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(myContext, "You chose " + suitText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            myTurn = false;
            makeComputerPlay(); 
        }
    }); 
    chooseSuitDialog.show();
}       

private void initCards() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 102; j < 115; j++) {
            int tempId = j + (i*100);
            Card tempCard = new Card(tempId);
            int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("card" + tempId, "drawable", myContext.getPackageName());
            Bitmap tempBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(myContext.getResources(), resourceId);
            scaledCardW = (int) (screenW/8);
            scaledCardH = (int) (scaledCardW*1.28);
            Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tempBitmap, scaledCardW, scaledCardH, false); 
            tempCard.setBitmap(scaledBitmap);
            deck.add(tempCard);
        }
    }
}

private void drawCard(List<Card> handToDraw) {
    handToDraw.add(0, deck.get(0));
    deck.remove(0);
    if (deck.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = discardPile.size()-1; i > 0 ; i--) {
            deck.add(discardPile.get(i));
            discardPile.remove(i);
            Collections.shuffle(deck,new Random());
        }
    }
}

private void dealCards() {
    Collections.shuffle(deck,new Random());
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        drawCard(myHand);
        drawCard(oppHand);
    }       
}

private boolean checkForValidDraw() {
    boolean canDraw = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < myHand.size(); i++) {
        int tempId = myHand.get(i).getId();
        int tempRank = myHand.get(i).getRank();
        int tempSuit = myHand.get(i).getSuit();
        if (validSuit == tempSuit || validRank == tempRank ||
            tempId == 108 || tempId == 208 || tempId == 308 || tempId == 408) {
            canDraw = false; 
        } 
    }
    return canDraw;
}

private void makeComputerPlay() {
    int tempPlay = 0;
    while (tempPlay == 0) {
        tempPlay = computerPlayer.makePlay(oppHand, validSuit, validRank);
        if (tempPlay == 0) {
            drawCard(oppHand);
        }
    }
    if (tempPlay == 108 || tempPlay == 208 || tempPlay == 308 || tempPlay == 408) {
        validRank = 8;
        validSuit = computerPlayer.chooseSuit(oppHand);
        String suitText = "";
        if (validSuit == 100) {
            suitText = "Diamonds";
        } else if (validSuit == 200) {
            suitText = "Clubs";
        } else if (validSuit == 300) {
            suitText = "Hearts";
        } else if (validSuit == 400) {
            suitText = "Spades";
        }
        Toast.makeText(myContext, "Computer chose " + suitText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        validSuit = Math.round((tempPlay/100) * 100);
        validRank = tempPlay - validSuit; 
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < oppHand.size(); i++) {
        Card tempCard = oppHand.get(i);
        if (tempPlay == tempCard.getId()) {
            discardPile.add(0, oppHand.get(i));
            oppHand.remove(i);              
        }
    }
    if (oppHand.isEmpty()) {
        endHand();
    }
    myTurn = true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_center"
      android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/unpressed_center" />
```

You should make draweble in same layout file for pres or not press version

Comment: could you please explain in more details. i'm using a custom view. i tried property animation also but doesn't work.

Comment: wich animate in game.I downloaded but which one?